# Angular Validator Pattern works in HTML but not in TypeScript

Tags: regex, angular, validation

Following Regular Expression does work in HTML like following example:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="mgmtIP" class="input-text" pattern="([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])">
```

But if I want to put that pattern in the FormGroup, the Validator isn't recognized:

```
mgmtIP: [host.mgmtIP, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$/)
          ]],
```

I tried putting it in a string with taking away the `^` and the `$`. That didn't work neither

Comment: Use single backslashes in `/.../` regex literal. `Validators.pattern(/^(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't work neither. I think the validator isn't even recognized by the application.

Comment: I would say that you have to remove those actually.

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried the example Wiktor gave me. It didn't work.

Comment: Even the HTML is not working, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsle5y

Comment: @N.Richli Then it is not the regex problem, show the code.

Comment: @N.Richli i was saying that it should not be done that way so no wonder it does not work.

Comment: The funny thing is, it works for me on that link @SachinGupta provided.,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew here there is a link [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlZgtXz8RyZbhZJDG-87SwRLP7VGyg)

Comment: @Antoniossss for me as well

Comment: Maybe you should create stackblitz from it.It wouild be better than that gdrive of yours.

Comment: Validation is working both with the HTML pattern and `Validators.pattern()`. Using both `/` the backslashes or 'string' works for `Validators.pattern()`. @N. Richli, If you are still facing issue, please create a sample on stackblitz.

Comment: Pretty strange.. Did it on StackBlitz and it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hodpwh

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer for this question. I was just stupid:
I had an initial form with the validators in the form array. Then I have pushed some new formgroups in there, where these validators weren't configured. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would not use regex for that as it obfuscates code and is hard to debug (you know this by now). Easier way to check for ip validity is to:

1. Allow only [0-9.]
2. Split by `.`
3. Check if segments are not empty and in range

I am not saying that regex is not viable for this, but for the sake of maintainability I would not go this way (or use well tested regex).

Comment: OP does not have a regex problem.